# Handling game states for an online RPG game

Tags: c++, multithreading, game, boost, state

I'm writing an ORPG. The code below is client-side.

I have a main thread looping in `Game::Run`:

```
Game::~Game()
{
    PopAllStates();
}

void Game::Run()
{
    sf::Event Event;

    while(Window->isOpen())
    {
        if(LoadQueueMutex.try_lock())
        {
            while(!LoadQueue.empty())
            {
                LoadQueue.front().first->Load(LoadQueue.front().second);
                LoadQueue.pop();
            }
            LoadQueueMutex.unlock();
        }
        while(Window->pollEvent(Event))
        {
            StateStack.top()->HandleEvent(Event);
        }
        Window->clear();
        StateStack.top()->Draw();
        Window->display();
        StateStack.top()->Update();
    }
}

void Game::AddToLoadQueue(Loadable* pLoadable, WorldPacket Argv)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(LoadQueueMutex);
    LoadQueue.push(std::make_pair(pLoadable, Argv));
}

void Game::PushState(GameState* pState)
{
    StateStack.push(pState);
}

void Game::PopState()
{
    if(!StateStack.empty())
    {
        delete StateStack.top();
        StateStack.pop();
    }
}

void Game::PopAllStates()
{
    while(!StateStack.empty())
    {
        PopState();
    }
}
```

And another thread waiting for a packet:

```
void WorldSession::Start()
{
    Packet = WorldPacket((uint16)MSG_NULL);

    boost::asio::async_read(Socket,
        boost::asio::buffer(Packet.GetDataWithHeader(), WorldPacket::HEADER_SIZE),
        boost::bind(&WorldSession::HandleHeader, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

When the packet "arrives", this is usually done because OpenGL breaks if loaded from another thread:

```
void WorldSession::HandleSomeCoolOpcode()
{
    //...
    sGame->AddToLoadQueue(pSomethingCool, Packet);
}
```

When the main thread loads the `Loadable*`, it will usually mess with the state stack:

```
void World::Load(WorldPacket Argv)
{
    //...
    sGame->PopState();
    sGame->PushState(this);
}
```

Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: what's the point of the pushState/popState mechanism? Is is possible to temporarily load/start a game, play it, and close it to return to the previously opened one?

Answer (score 11):

- Your variables and functions should either be in camelCase or another naming convention that differentiates them from user-defined types (such as `Game` here), which are capitalized.
- If a parameter is not supposed to be modified, and it's not a primitive type (such as an `int`), pass it by `const`-reference in order to avoid an unnecessary copy.

  In both `AddToLoadQueue()` and `PushState()`, you're passing a raw pointer to an object that will not be modified within the function.  This is also discouraged as you should refrain from passing raw pointers to functions in C++, mostly due to issues such as [dangling pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).  If you still need to pass around pointers, pass [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) instead (if you have C++11).

  `Argv` in `AddToLoadQueue()` should also be passed by `const`-reference, not by value.
- Prefer *not* to cast the C-way in C++:

  > ```
  > Packet = WorldPacket((uint16)MSG_NULL);
  > ```

  Cast the C++ way, with `static_cast<>` in this case:

  ```
  Packet = WorldPacket(static_cast<uint16>(MSG_NULL));
  ```

  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255015) for more information on different types of casts.
- It's not exactly clear how `StateStack` is supposed to be used here.  You use `delete` on its elements in `PopState()`, so it's assumed that `push()` uses `new` to add new elements, which then means it's a dynamic container.  Either way, this implementation should be provided here.

  However, if this is entirely identical to a regular dynamic stack, then just use [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).  It will also handle all the memory-management for you (no `new` and `delete` necessary).

  ```
  std::stack<GameState> stateStack;
  ```

  You'll also no longer need to use a separate `top()` and `pop()` when popping a state:

  ```
  stateStack.pop();
  ```
- If `PopAllStates()` is just done in the destructor, then you can just put that code there instead of defining a separate function.

  It also calls `empty()` twice (`PopState()` also calls `empty()`), which isn't necessary.  If this is only needed in the destructor, put that code (with just one check) into it:

  ```
  Game::~Game()
  {
      while (!StateStack.empty())
      {
          delete StateStack.top();
          StateStack.pop();
      }
  }
  ```

  If you use `std::stack`, you'll just need a call to `pop()`, not `top()`.

Answer (score 11):

First and biggest point: I *really* dislike spreading mutex locking throughout the code if it can be avoided. The first (and biggest) thing I'd change would be to create a `concurrent_stack` that handles the locking and unlocking internally.

```
template <class T>
class concurrent_stack { 
    std::stack<T> data;
    Boost::mutex guard;
public:
    void push(T const &t) { 
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(guard);
        data.push(t);
    }

    void pop() {
          boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(guard);
          data.pop();
    }
    // and so on.
};
```

With this in place, the rest of the code can generally ignore threading issues for that stack, and just push and pop as needed. Obviously there are limits to that, but for the case at hand, it's probably adequate. The result is considerably safer code--it basically eliminates the possibility of forgetting to lock the mutex when you manipulate the stack.

I'd (sort of) disagree with @Jamal on his first point. While I agree with him that you should do something to distinguish type names from variable names, I don't think camelCase is the only (or necessarily best) convention to use. Personally, I prefer what's sometimes called "snake case", which uses underscores to separate words, so (for example) `state_stack` instead of `StateStack`. In any case, the basic point is pretty simple: you should use some convention to distinguish types from variables, but camelCase isn't the only convention available.

Comment: While I up-voted this, I don't know if it's a good idea. I don't know about `boost::mutex`, but locking is generally an expensive operation. For instance, in his `Game::Run()` function, he performs 4 `LoadQueue.*` operations in a single critical section. With your strategy, it seems like he would be creating (implicitly) 4 different critical sections for each operation. I would imagine that the overhead could be quite excessive.

Comment: @jliv902: As you say, this *can* be an issue, but when/if it is, I'd prefer to handle it the same basic way: do all the locking in a single class, not spread throughout all the code.